# CSS Positioning Issue

Tags: css

I am working on a web site where there are two box items on the main content of the page and it looks something like this:

```
-----------------  ----------------
|               |  |              |
|               |  |              |
|               |  |              |
|               |  |              |
-----------------  ----------------
```

When the browser dimensions are at 1024 x 768 and above, the site looks OK.  But when I resize the browser to a smaller dimension horizontally, the right box "collides" with the left box and there is some overlap.

I have a basic understanding of CSS, but the site I'm taking over is heavily into CSS.

What I want is when I resize the browser to a smaller dimension, I want the right box to stay right where it's at and have a horizontal scroll bar appear at the bottom of the browser.

Here is a screenshot:

http://www.skoolrox.com/collision.jpg

I know I need to brush up on my CSS, but my question is, when I do my search on CSS,  I want to look for keywords like:

CSS, fixed, positioning.

Since I'm no CSS guru, does this sound right or am I missing additional keywords in my search.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed dimension **wrapper** around your elements.

**Here's an example**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="float-left">

  </div>
  <div class="float-left">

  </div>
  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
}
  #wrapper .float-left {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give each box a `display:inline-block;` and then place them in a container.

```
#container{
    width:300px;
}

#one, #two{
    background:red;
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1em;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/J2pZX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="flt-left column">

            </div>
            <div class="flt-right column">

            </div>
            <br style="clear: both" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#container
{   min-width:450px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#wrapper
{   width:100%;
}
.flt-left
{   float:left;
}
.flt-right
{ float:right;
}
#wrapper .column
{   width:49%;
    background:#f00;
    height:100px;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sddf/3/)